# Does AWS Load Balancer Controller support wildcard character "*"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

Background: I'm new to AWS and EKS. And my system is AWS Load Balancer Controller + Ingress + Service + Deployment.

Now I need to write an Ingress to match `"/a/*/b"` to service-a. But [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) only support prefix `"/*"` or `"/a/*"`, not `"/a/*/b"`.

Although ALB [support this path pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions). But AWS Load Balancer Controller didn't notice how to use this by ingress.([doc here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/ingress/annotations/))

I Tried to use `/a/*/b` as ingress prefix, and got `Failed build model due to ingress: namespacea/server-a-ingress: prefix path shouldn't contain wildcards: /a/*/b`.

Question: How can I route `/a/*/b` to serivce-a? Does AWS Load Balancer Controller has CRD or something to to this?

Thanks for any tips!